# Why is this unable to write the response by using response.writeHead and response.write?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to node.js. I am unable to figure out why the code for writing the response inside `if` and `else` loop of `'/socket.html'` case is not running. I am getting 200 status code and blank response every time on the url `localhost:8001/socket.html` irrespective of whether `if` part is executing or `else` part. Here is my server file. This is the tutorial I am following [Node.js Tutorial With Socket.io](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/)

```
var http = require('http');
var i = 0;
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log("Connection");
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log(path);
    switch (path) {
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("oops-dne");

                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    response.write(data, "utf-8");
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("oops-dne-default case");
            break;
    }
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8001);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `response.end()` after you write your response head/data.

Comment: Yes it worked !! but i still don't have any idea why it was not working .

Comment: @iroh [`response.end`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) method signals to the server that all of the response headers and body have been sent; that server should consider this message complete. The method, response.end(), **MUST be called on each response.**